# Create mongo user with java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using the `mongo-java-driver` version 3.0.2 to connect to an instance of MongoDB v2.4, and can't figure out how to add a user to a database. I've tried the following but keep getting `no such cmd: createUser`:

```
private void createUser(MongoDatabase database) {
    Map<String, Object> commandArguments = new BasicDBObject();
    commandArguments.put("createUser", "testuser");
    commandArguments.put("pwd", "testpassword");
    String[] roles = {"readWrite"};
    commandArguments.put("roles", roles);
    BasicDBObject command = new BasicDBObject(commandArguments);
    database.runCommand(command);
}
```

Comment: This should work. My guess is that you are connecting to a V 2.4 database  where `createUser` didn't exist. It used to be called `addUser`, deprecated in 2.6 and removed in 3

Comment: Yeah it is a 2.4 DB, but using `addUser` above fails with much the same: `no such cmd: addUser`

Comment: Indeed, in 2.4v `addUser` only exist as a shell helper but no command. Try  running `db.addUser` (no parenthesis) from shell to inspect what does it call.

Comment: It's likely just hacking around in `system.users` directly ( from memory ) and therefore probably just plain collection manipulation.

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060870/mongodb-how-to-create-an-authenticated-db-via-java-driver) might help you.

Comment: created command seems wrong, Normally it should be like this`db.addUser({"user":"testuser","pwd":"testpassword","roles":["role1","role2"]})` , but your generated command looks like `{"addUser":"testuser","pwd":"testpassword","roles":["role1","role2"]}`